# matplotlib yaxis out of order

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've been  trying to plot a bar graph from a vector in matplotlib, and I did got a graph, but the Y-axis is completly strange and I've tried to search on it, but all I could found was about the matplotlib sorting the items by alphabetical order, wich is not the case, anyways, in the following will be the two vectors and the generated image.

Image of the graph:

[image]

Image of how the graph should be:

[image]

```
-66.5135;0
-66.5115;1
-66.5095;0
-66.5075;0
-66.5055;0
-66.5035;0
-66.5015;0
-66.4995;0
-66.4975;0
-66.4955;0
-66.4935;0
-66.4915;1
-66.4895;1
-66.4875;0
-66.4855;0
-66.4835;0
-66.4815;1
-66.4795;0
-66.4775;1
-66.4755;0
-66.4735;0
-66.4715;0
-66.4695;0
```

A piece of the CSV where the data comes from.

Comment: What do you expect me to fix? Where is your code?

Comment: Can you provide us the code? Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @HarvIpan, for future reference if you type `[MCVE]` into the comments, it automatically creates the following link for you: [MCVE]. Might save you some typing in the future!

Comment: Are your x and y values strings?  You can convert them with the float() and int() functions.